# Core Data- different data depending on app version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a Swift 3 IOS 10 app using standard core data stack. Some of my users have reported losing their data when upgrading to the latest version of the app. What seems to be happening is that a new data store is created even though the model has not changed, and there is no migration.

I can recreate this by getting the published version- data set 1 shows up. But when I push my dev version to my device, data set 1 is gone. I can add a record to data set 2 and it persists fine. But if I go back to the app store and get the published version, data set 1 shows up again.

Can someone explain why this is happening and to prevent it. Am I missing something simple? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the store URL changing between the versions for reason X. It would seem possible since you can flip between the v1 and v2 stores by changing version.

Comment: So can each version of the app have its own store in a different directory? I had thought that there was only ever one version of the sqlLite store.

Comment: At the point you call `addPersistentStoreWithType` with a URL. Are you sure those are identical between versions. Thats the question :-). It seem like you have two physical stores in play here.

Answer (score 0):

I had simular issue and when I changed this section in the AppDelegate it fixed it for me.

```
 lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]) //THIS LINE
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Comment: Is the App Store version Swift3?  Do you use source control so that you can go back and compare the AppDelegate before convert to Swift 3?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's responses. I do use source control and confirmed that nothing changed. The issue seems to be not checking that there is an existing data store. Per Apple's documentation, when an app is upgraded to a new version, the contents of the documents directory are copied from the previous version's directory, and then deleted. This did not seem to be consistently happening. Adding code to check for an existing data store when the app opens, and then copying it to the working directory if found, seems to have solved this issue.